# Riddle: Tell me What it is?

Tags: riddle

I came around this recently. Kind of like it. So here we go ...

> If you have one, you don't share it;
>   If you share it, you don't have it.

**What is it ?**

Comment: any reason for downvote ?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but If i could venture a guess, I think you were downvoted because this is one of the most widely known and famous riddle in existance.(really, it must be plastered all over the internet)

Comment: Thanks for explanation but its really embarrassing when people downvote without explanation.

Comment: I think it is not necessarily bad if the riddle is well known, as far as i know, it is accepted to post these, even though you could argue self answering might be the option to take with these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it

> the secret
>  Being a gossiper my self, this was easy :)

Comment: That was quick.